# Apache Pig - Substring in other string

Tags: regex, apache-pig

Currently I'm working in Pig and I'm trying to check whether a field value (which is a `chararray`) is present in another field (also a `chararray`). 
Here's an example.

File `t.txt`:

```
1;This is a banana which is yellow.;Fruit;Banana
2;This is not about fruit but about Apple Inc.;Company;Apple
```

In the examples above, I'd like to check if the last field (i.e. `Banana` and `Apple`) is present in the second field (the sentence). Here's my pig script so far:

```
a = LOAD 't.txt' using PigStorage(';') AS (id:chararray, sentence:chararray, kind:chararray, search:chararray);

b = FOREACH a GENERATE id, LOWER(sentence) as sent:chararray, kind, LOWER(search) as srch:chararray;

c = FILTER b BY sent MATCHES '.* srch .*';
```

The goal I'm trying to achieve is to get the bigrams surrounding the search word. To give a concrete example, this is what I'm looking for (or in another form):

```
(1,Fruit,{(a, banana),(banana, which})
(2,Company,{(about, apple),(apple, inc.})
```

So, my question is: how can I use the field search from the schema to match the field sentence from the schema?

Comment: So you want a sentence from t.txt that matches with kind and search from the second schema? So are to looking for a sentence with all the words or just one word from any of the tuple from list.

Comment: So to give an example: from each row, I want to extract a value (contained in the field "search") from a sentence (contained in the field "sentence"). It is very similar to the situation where you use MATCHES, but with a given pattern. However, as the pattern, here, I'd like to use the value contained in the field "search" instead of a given pattern. So to say, the pattern is dynamic and changes for each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an UDF. Pass the sentence and search item to the UDF.In the UDF split the sentence into words and iterate over the words.If the word matches then get the word before and after the search item.

**PigScript**

```
REGISTER GetSurroundingWords.jar;
DEFINE GetSurroundingWords com.mypackages.GetSurroundingWords();

A = LOAD 'test11.txt' using PigStorage(';') AS (id:chararray, sentence:chararray, kind:chararray, search:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE id, LOWER(sentence) as sent:chararray, kind, LOWER(search) as srch:chararray;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE id,kind,GetSurroundingWords(sent,srch);
DUMP C;
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Java UDF**

```
package com.mypackages;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;

public class GetSurroundingWords extends EvalFunc<String> 
{
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException
    {
        if(input != null && input.size() != 0)
        {
            String sInputString = input.toString();
            String sOutputString = "";
            try
            {
                if(sInputString != null && !sInputString.isEmpty())
                {
                    String [] sInputStringItems = sInputString.split(",");
                    String sSentence = sInputStringItems[0].replace('(', ' ').trim();
                    String [] sWords = sSentence.split(" ");
                    String sSearchItem = sInputStringItems[1].replace(')',' ').trim();

                    for(int iIndex = 0;iIndex < sWords.length;iIndex ++)
                    {
                        if(sWords[iIndex].equals(sSearchItem))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                sOutputString = "(" + sWords[--iIndex] + "," + sSearchItem + ")";
                            }catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                sOutputString = "(" + sSearchItem + ")";
                            }

                            int iNextItem = iIndex + 2;
                            try
                            {
                                sOutputString =  sOutputString + "," + "(" + sSearchItem + "," + sWords[iNextItem] + ")"; 
                            }catch(Exception ex)
                            {
                                sOutputString = sOutputString + "," + "(" + sSearchItem  + ")";
                            }
                            return sOutputString;
                        }
                    }           
                }
                else
                { 
                    return null;
                }   
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {  
                return null;
            }
            return sOutputString;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RobinTrietsch Cool, you might have to make some minor code optimizations to the java UDF,especially the string concatenation,loop etc.I am not an expert in Java

Comment: I will look into that, though I'm not a Java expert either. At least I've got a solid starting point thanks to you!